# Hierarchy of functions

Tags: analysis

I am aware of the hierarchy of functions in order of their rates of growth (exp grow faster than polynomials etc). Is it also true that something like, say $e^{5x}$ will ( for some sufficiently large $x$) exceed any SUM of terms made up exclusively of polynomials AND lesser exponentials: $x$>0

For instance, is it true that

$e^{5x}$ > 555555$e^{4.999x}$ + 3450000$e^{3x}$+10000$e^{2x}$+ 999999$x^{500}$

for some value of $x$ ?

Comment: Yes, because, say: $$\begin{array}{rl}&\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{555555e^{4.999x}+3450000e^{3x}+10000e^{2x}+999999x^{500}}{e^{5x}}\\=& 555555\cdot \lim_{x\to +\infty}e^{-0.001x}+3450000\cdot\lim_{x\to +\infty}e^{-2x}+10000\cdot\lim_{x\to +\infty}e^{-3x}+999999\cdot \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^{500}}{e^{5x}}\\=&555555\cdot 0+3450000\cdot 0+10000\cdot 0+999999\cdot 0\\=&0\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you for that detailed reply, it's just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already got a perfect answer by @Stinking Bishop in the comments, let me provide an alternative way to prove your claim.

Since $e^x$ is an increasing function, $e^{ax}>e^{bx}$ when $a>b$ and $x>0$. Thus all the exponential terms in
$$
  f(x) = 555555e^{4.999x} + 3450000e^{3x}+10000e^{2x}+ 999999x^{500}
$$
are dominates by a multiply of $e^{4.999x}$, specifically
$$
  f(x) < Ae^{4.999x} + 999999^{500},
$$
where $A = 555555 + 3450000 + 10000$.

The Taylor series for $e^x$ is
$$
  e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} > \frac{x^{501}}{501!}
= \frac{x}{501!} x^{500},
$$
where $\frac{x}{501!}$ is greater than $999999$ for $x$ large enough. Thus $e^{4.999x}> e^x> 999999x^{500}$ for $x$ large enough. Consequently,
$$
  f(x) < (A+1) e^{4.999x},
$$
for $x$ large enough. Finally,
$$
 (A+1) e^{4.999x} < e^{5x}
$$
whenever
$$
  x > \frac{\log(A+1)}{5-4.999} = 1000 \log(A+1).
$$
We conclude that $f(x)< e^{5x}$ for $x$ large enough.

Comment: That's great, I really like your explanation because it's taught me a new way of thinking! Thank you.